# Animating a tracked object outside camera solver's frame range

Tags: animation, camera, tracking

I have an object tracked using a camera solver.

This solver was created using footage where all the track points were visible. But there are still some frames at the beginning of the shot where I want my object to be animated.

I duplicated animation keyframes on those previous frames, but Blender does not display the object on those frames! I guess the object is linked to the solver's frame range ? Is it possible to force animation&display of my object outside of this range, or do I have to go back & modify the range of my solver?

I hope it's clear :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, so far we've solved the issue by copying the tracked object, then animating this duplicate on the desired frames.